# What's the JS event handler for smartphone text input "done"

Tags: javascript, textfield, smartphone

Is there a way to catch when the user hits "done" on the input text field?

I want to call a function when the user closes the textfield but I could not find how

Comment: I think that would be the `blur` event (the opposite of `focus`): `input.addEventListener( 'blur', function( ev ) { ... } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onblur or focusout events.

```
    <input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
```

or

```
    <input type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```